# How to wrap kendoAutoComplete in an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm trying to wrap kendoAutocomplete in an Angular directive. The problem is that I get the following error message: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'e(data)')

Any ideas what could be the cause of the problem ?

```
<input id="selectDomain" select-kendo=""/>

-----

var kendo = angular.module('kendo',[]);

kendo.directive('selectKendo', function () {

    var data = [
        "Sweden",
        "Switzerland",
        "Turkey",
        "Ukraine",
        "United Kingdom",
        "Vatican City"
    ];

    return {

        restrict: 'A',

        scope: {
        },

        link: function (scope, element) {

            console.log(element);

            $(element).kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: data,
                filter: "startswith",
                placeholder: "Domain",
                separator: ", "
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? I mean which line in the above code?

Comment: Be sure to use non-minified source files when debugging this way the stacktrace will contain lines that can be inspected and that have function and variable names to help us understand what is going wrong.

Comment: The error happens as soon as I input something into the input control that exists in the data array.

Comment: Works now on my computer at home. Not sure why it is not working on my computer at the office.